# how to remove \t char from string

Tags: c#

I have a string that contains some unwanted characters,so I want to remove those characters. I am reading unwanted characters from xml file.

```
"<UnwantedChars>\t,@</UnwantedChars>"

sUnwantedChar = xml.ReadNodeValue("\UnwantedChars")
```

I have tried

```
str = str.Replace(sUnwantedChar.Split(',')[0],string.Empty)
str = str.Replace(sUnwantedChar.Split(',')[1],string.Empty)
```

In final result, `@` is removed but tab i.e. `\t` is not removed.

Comment: what is the structure of your xml?

Comment: Have you checked what `sUnwantedChar` contains?

Comment: "<UnwantedChars>\t,@</UnwantedChars>"

Comment: If your code did work, it would be horribly inefficient. You are calling `String.Split()` twice. Call it once and assign the result to an array. Then use the array. Splitting the string can be a costly action. No point in doing it multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

You should encode the tab in your XML, like this:

```
"<UnwantedChars>&#09;,@</UnwantedChars>"
```

Otherwise you are feeding the replace with the literal `"\t"` that is a string of two charachters, a `backslash` and a `t`, and obviously it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that the following code returns the *string* `"\t"` (in reality, it is `\\t`), not the *character* `'\t'`:

```
string unwantedChar = sUnwantedChar.Split(',')[0];
```

You could do something like this:

```
if (unwantedChar.Equals(@"\t"))
    unwantedChar = "\t";
```

Comment: yes.. I am thinking the same..How can i overcome on this.

Comment: instead of doing this, can i change my xml node value? If yes then what

Comment: Of course you can, as Felice Pollano suggests. Has the added bonus that you don't have to hardcode exceptions for every possible control character (`\n`, `\r`, etc.). OTOH, `&#09;` is not as easily understood as `\t`.